# Strange WndProc bug in .Net. VB.Net more specifically

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wndproc

ETA: I use visual studio 2008 express edition.

If I override WndProc and mess up somehow, I'll usually backtrack by commenting out code until it works again.

The strange thing with WndProc though is you can strip it down to:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc((m))
End Sub
```

and it still throws the error.

I have to remove the code and retype it in to reset the error.

Anyone else experienced this?

ETA:

Answered below by Chris Haas.

I hadn't realised, but this problem must only have occurred when I'd used code from reflector. Reflector mis-translates to vb.net and inserts extra brackets into the calls to WndProc base.

Comment: Its an 'Error creating window handle' at: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)

Comment: It is so wierd. I got it working by cutting all the code out and re-overriding. Then i pasted the code back bit-by-bit and kept testing to make sure it was ok. Eventually I ended up with all the code there and it worked. Then I tried copying and pasting the whole block of the code in there....it doesn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you wrap an argument in parenthesis you are overriding the `ByRef` call and instead calling it `ByVal`. See [Argument Not Being Modified by Procedure Call - Underlying Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bkbyhtx.aspx)

Just change the code to:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers, looks like that is it. The code I was starting with was from reflector which is mistranslating to vb.net and inserting the brackets when they shouldn't be there. Mystery solved!